# How to create liferay Service xml for multiple foreign key of same primary key?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity, liferay-aui

[image]

I know the question might be confusing,any ways I will explain it.

Basically I have two tables. Student and Course where studentid and courseid are their corresponding primary keys.

In the Student table I have two attributes  courseid and courseidbackup both are key(FK) to the course table.
This is the service xml I am using, but it shows build unsuccessful.

What am I missing here? How to create service xml to achieve this ?

```
 <service-builder package-path="com.students.db">
<author>bugs</author>
<namespace>students</namespace>
<entity name="Student" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
<column name="studentId" type="long" primary="true" />
<column name="studentName" type="String" />

<column name="coursesid" type="Collection" entity="Course" mapping-table="Students_Courses"/>
<column name="coursesidbackup" type="Collection" entity="Course" mapping-table="Students_Courses"/>
</entity>
<entity name="Course" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
<column name="courseId" type="long" primary="true" />
<column name="courseName" type="String" />
<column name="courseDetails" type="String" />
<column name="students" type="Collection" entity="Student" mapping-table="Students_Courses" />
</entity>
</service-builder>
```

Comment: AFAIK Liferay service builder does not provide support for foreign key

Comment: Ok. any other suggestion?

Comment: Manually you may write code for handling foreign-key relation with student/course entity

Comment: That is after building this service xml successfully  right?

Comment: Similarly to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273631/liferay-service-builder-6-2-many-to-one-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the same mapping table - Students_Courses - in both cases. Try e.g. Students_Backupcourses as the second option. Otherwise I'd be puzzled how that mapping table should handle that relationship. As mentioned in the comments, typically Liferay doesn't enforce any foreign key relationship in the db model, but this would be as close as you get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Well i tried it but my build service is still not succesfull.It generates duplicate methods

Answer (score 0):

change your  mapping-`table="Students_Courses"`
to this-->  mapping-`table="Students_Course"`