# Liferay Service Builder 6.2: Many to one relationships

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I want to create a one to many relationships and I've used the following service.xml:

```
<entity name="Student" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="studentId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="courses" type="Collection" entity="Course"/>
</entity>

<entity name="Course" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="courseId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="studentId" type="long"/>
</entity>
```

My Problem is that nothing gets created for the collections method. No Exception, nothing.
The classes are generated and the simple getter methods are there but no getCourse().

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The getters are not automatically created for you. Each entity represents a table in the database so you'll have to create any getters that you'd find useful. Luckily, Service Builder is also capable of generating this if you need.

First, we ask Service Builder to create a mapping table between `Students` and `Courses`.

```
<entity name="Student" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="studentId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <column name="courses" type="Collection" entity="Course" mapping-table="Courses_Students" />
</entity>

<entity name="Course" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="courseId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <column name="students" type="Collection" entity="Student" mapping-table="Courses_Students" />
</entity>
```

Next, we create the appropriate method in `CourseLocalServiceImpl`:

```
public List<Course> getStudentCourses(long studentId)
    throws PortalException, SystemException {

    return coursePersistence.getCourses(studentId);
}
```

To get `Courses` from the `Student` object we create method inside the generated `StudentImpl.java`:

```
public List<Course> getCourses() throws Exceptions {
    return CorseLocalServiceUtil.getStudentCourses(getStudentId());
}
```

Finally, regenerate your classes by running `ant build-service`.

Now we can get all the courses a student is taking by writing:

```
List<Course> courses = CourseLocalServiceUtil.getStudentCourses(studentId);
```

or

```
List<Course> courses = student.getCourses();
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But it leaves us with unwanted database columns (studentId) for the course table, right ?

Comment: In the Service Builder XML you've provided above, `studentId` was already a column of the `course` table.

Comment: ok, true ;) That´s my mistake. Is there a way to get rid of it ? To only have the getter for the List ? And, second question: Is there no way to get those elements from a Student Element ?

Comment: Your answer shows many-to-many relationship instead of one-to-many as asked by OP, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Liferay in all its version have specified documentation, that helps to move from top to bottom approach.

Please refer this first:

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/define-your-object-relational-map-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en

For spontaneous add following code

```
<entity name="Student" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="studentId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="courses" type="Collection" entity="Course"/>
</entity>

<entity name="Course" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="courseId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="studentId" type="long"/>

    <finder name="courseId" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="courseId" />
    </finder>

    <finder name="studentId" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="studentId" />
    </finder>
</entity>
```

Run build-service and on successful execution you will see the getter setter methods.